# Injectivity of normal operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a bounded normal operator on a Hilbert space $H$. I know that
$$
\ker A=(\text{ran} A^{*})^{\perp}.
$$
What I've been unsuccesfully trying to prove is that $A$ is injective iff its range is dense. I'd appreciate any guidance on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that $(\mathrm{ran}\, A)^\perp = \{0\}$ if and only if $\ker A = \{0\}$.

The key is that $A^*$ is injective on the range of $A$: if $A^*Ax = 0$ then 
$$ 0 = \langle x,A^*Ax  \rangle = \langle Ax , Ax \rangle = \|Ax\|^2 $$ so that $Ax = 0$. Similarly, $A$ is injective on the range of $A^*$. This means that $$\ker A = \ker A^*A \quad \text{and}\quad \ker A^* = \ker AA^*.$$

If in addition $A$ is normal you get
$$ \ker A = \ker A^*A = \ker A A^* = \ker A^* = (\mathrm{ran}\, A)^\perp.$$

Comment: Great answer, thank you!